# How can I make a window appear on top of another window, without closing when I click the second?

Tags: windows-7, windows

So basically I want to be able to learn about blender, but it has been proving difficult due to the small size of my laptop screen, and trying to run a minimised youtube video beside blender like this

[image: An Image]

is not happening. So I would like to be able to do something like this

[image: Another one]

so that I can use blender while the tutorial is running, so that the video doesnt hide behind the blender window when I click on it (the blender window).
I've tried a bit to sort this out myself, mostly google, but I am unsure what to google, and I've rooted arount in my computer for an in built function, but no luck.

I'm running Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use a simple, one-line [Auto Hot Key](https://autohotkey.com/) (AHK) script to do this.

```
^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

When you press **Ctrl-Space** the currently selected window should stay on top!

Comment: Thans. Still have to test it, but since I have AHK ready installed I suspect it will work.

Comment: Also this a toggle right? So I can disable it  by clicking ctrl-space?

Comment: No problem. Good luck learning blender!

Answer (score 1):

This app claims to do it. I havn't tested it so no warranties

https://img.labnol.org/di/always-on-top.zip